# No delay in jQuery statement

Tags: jquery

I want some characters to appear gradually, so i've built this script. However, the delay seems not to execute at all - i tried to put it to several thousands with no change in result. What do i miss?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var 
        i,
        d = [500, 300, 600, 1000],
        t = "String";

    $("body")
        .delay(flashDuration[0])
        .animate({ backgroundColor: "#888888" }, d[1])
        .animate({ backgroundColor: "#222222" }, d[2])
        .animate({ backgroundColor: "#F8ECC2" }, d[3], null, function () {
            for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
                $("<span>" + t.substr(i, 1) + "</span>")
                    .addClass("hidden")
                    .delay(i * 2000) /* this delay doesn't execute */
                    .addClass("visible")
                    .appendTo("#floatingName");

        });
});
```

Please don't bite my head off for d being duration and t being title. I abbreviated the names because every programmer loves cryptic, non-self explanatory, short variable names. Right? Seriously, i tried to avoid wrapping.

Also, i tried to post in on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/8XUpL/1/) but the example doesn't even flash the screen, let alone executes the delay properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, jQuery still doesn't support color animations natively.

Here's a version of your code on jsFiddle with a color animation extension included:

http://jsfiddle.net/8XUpL/4/

Comment: I see NO difference in the codes WHATSOEVER. Yet, i see a different behavior. Have i gone crazy?! (And yes, i'm using jQuery UI, which i forgot about. Still the main question about delay remains.)

Comment: You had mootools selected as framework on your jsFiddle. I'm not very into jsFiddle but I suppose that was one important difference.

Comment: Yeah, like @MrAzulay said, you didn't have jQuery selected.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of animate() is the time the animation should animate over. Not time before the animation starts. You should put in delay() between every animate() in your chain.

```
$("body")
    .delay(flashDuration[0])
    .animate({ backgroundColor: "#888888" }).delay(d[1])
    .animate({ backgroundColor: "#222222" }).delay(d[2])
```

and so on...

You could also use the queue option of animate() to make animations stack instead of running immediately after each other.

All explained here
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

---

**Edit**

Delay does not delay the execution the script it only delays the next item in the animation queue. So it cant be used in this way. You should use setTimeout instead.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Comment: No, that part is right. My question is about the delay when showing spans, not the flashing (which occurs as i want it it). I want the letters in the spans to get re-classed to .visible after a while, which occurs momentaneously right now.

Comment: Oh sorry i just assumed you didn't want that cause you called the variable d (for delay). Check my updated answer _^

Comment: Haha, i got myself in problem. The variable name is actually the delay while flashing and before the letters are to be displayed. THEN i realized i can shove in all that in the callback function but kept the name. Sorry to mislead you. Nevertheless, it seems to me that delay IS the correct choice. I want to change the class name, wait for a period of time, then change the class name again (or add it, actually).